# Bootstrap toggle button stays grey

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Normal:
[image]

First click:
[image]

Second click:
[image]

On the second click, it stays grey and only clears on action somewhere else e.g. mouse click, select. How can I make it return to original state when deselected?

Comment: I think there's some issues with `toggleClass` but without html and js  I can't say more. Provide some fiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>
    <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Maybe</button>
     <button id="btn3" type="button" class="btn btn-default">No</button>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 var flag1 = 1, flag2 = 1, flag3 = 1;
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            if (flag1 == 2) {
                $("#btn1").css("background-color", "white");
                flag1 = 1;
            } else {
                $("#btn1").css("background-color", "lightgray");
                flag1 = 2;
            }
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            if (flag2 == 2) {
                $("#btn2").css("background-color", "white");
                flag2 = 1;
            } else {
                $("#btn2").css("background-color", "lightgray");
                flag2 = 2;
            }
        });
        $("#btn3").click(function () {
            if (flag3 == 2) {
                $("#btn3").css("background-color", "white");
                flag3 = 1;
            } else {
                $("#btn3").css("background-color", "lightgray");
                flag3 = 2;
            }
        });
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7644/)